# Way to show curves intersect each other through derivatives and vector question.

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors

!<sup>-></sup>a!=a,then find the value of-:
(all a's are vectors and i,j,k are unit vectors )(! is modulus).
!a x i!<sup>2</sup>+!a x j!<sup>2</sup>+!a x k!<sup>2</sup>.
Can you also suggest something for-:show that the curves  xy=a<sup>2</sup> and x<sup>2</sup> +y<sup>2</sup> =2a<sup>2</sup> touch each other.

Comment: What's your question about the first one? If you write $a=\langle x, y, z\rangle$ (or however you write your vectors) you should be able to come up with expressions for $a\times i$ and the rest pretty easily I would think.

Comment: You are suggesting !a x i != !a! ?

Comment: I don't think I am. So far as I can see, if I write the three components of $a$ as $\langle x, y, z\rangle$, then the value of $a\times i$ is $\langle 0,z,-y\rangle$. (I'm using the "determinant" form of the cross product and expanding along the bottom row, where two of the values are zero.) That means that $|a\times i|=y^2+z^2$. Continue on for the others, and add.

Comment: @tabstop.Sorry, I don't understand, I understand this much only-: let a-> = xi + yj + zk , but not the value of a x i.. How you get (0,-z,y) ?

Comment: Well, it's a cross product. You've mentioned a textbook in the question, so presumably that's one place to look, or you can look it up on the interwebs (lots of sites to choose from, so pick one you like) (for example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cross+product).

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your notation, but you probably wanted to write something similar to: $|\vec a|=a$ and $|a\times i|^2+|a\times j|^2+|a\times k|^2$ or maybe $|\vec a\times \mathbf i|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf j|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf k|^2$. They can be typeset as: `$|\vec a|=a$`, `$|a\times i|^2+|a\times j|^2+|a\times k|^2$`, `$|\vec a\times \mathbf i|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf j|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf k|^2$`.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand correctly the notation in the original question, but anyway.

---

$\vec a\times\mathbf i=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\times(1,0,0)=(0,a_3,-a_2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $|\vec a\times\mathbf i|^2=a_2^2+a_3^3$
Similarly you get: $|\vec a\times\mathbf j|^2=a_1^2+a_3^3$ and $|\vec a\times\mathbf k|^2=a_1^2+a_2^3$.

Together you get: $|\vec a\times \mathbf i|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf j|^2+|\vec a\times \mathbf k|^2=2(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)=2|\vec a|^2$.

---

The curve $x^2+y^2=2a^2$ is a circle going through the point $(a,a)$. You can see that the tangent at this point has slope $-1$. (This is clear from the symmetry of $x$ and $y$-coordinate.)

Similarly, $xy=a^2$ is a hyperbole going through the point $(a,a)$ and the tangent at this point has slope $-1$.

Comment: So since the slopes are equal , they intersect each other . Is the converse true (I don't think so at all)?thank you,I appreciate it a lot

Comment: No, they touch. You can sketch the situation easily, you can try [plot on WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/p7c37z4) using `plot x^2+y^2=2, xy=1, x+y=2, x+y=-2` to see what the situaion looks like.

Comment: Actually this is an exam question and I specifically had to get the answer through derivatives, so I conclude this -: I was just supposed to take out slopes of both the equations (they would be equal and hence lines intersect).

Comment: i, j and k are unit vectors , you got that ?

Comment: I guess we do not understand each other. As you can see from the picture, they do not intersect, they touch. (They have the same tangent line.) You even asked in your post to show whether they touch.

Comment: I meant touch only but I can't prove it by plotting a graph but through derivatives only...that is what I mean ( I thought touch was same as intersect , i didnt think if it touches then it may or may not intersect )

Comment: So I just had to take out the slopes of the tangent ( through derivatives) and since they were equal , it means they touch !such a simple question ,damn ! Lost marks for nothing .

Comment: Awesome , I understand everything now ....after one day suddenly....(without any deliberate effort or thought)

Answer (score 0):

If two curves are to touch each other then the equation of the tangent at the common point is same for both the curves.